# Using RxJava for email login validation, an observable is emitting twice

Tags: java, android, functional-programming, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm making a simple login form (email and password) to try and bolster my reactive programming skillset. I'm having some trouble getting the email field validation to work the way I want it.

Here's my code:

```
    final Observable<CharSequence> email = RxTextView.textChanges(emailView);

    Observable<Boolean> emailIsValid = email.map(new Func1<CharSequence, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(CharSequence charSequence) {
            Log.d("asdf", "emailIsValid call: " + charSequence);
            return Pattern.matches(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.pattern(), charSequence);
        }
    });
    RxView.focusChanges(emailView)
            .withLatestFrom(emailIsValid, new Func2<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Boolean hasFocus, Boolean emailIsValid) {
                    return (!hasFocus && !emailIsValid);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Boolean showError) {
                    if (showError) {
                        emailInputLayout.setError("Enter a valid email");
                    } else {
                        emailInputLayout.setError(null);
                    }
                }
            });
    Observable<CharSequence> password = RxTextView.textChanges(passwordView);

    Observable.combineLatest(emailIsValid, password,
            new Func2<Boolean, CharSequence, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(Boolean emailIsValid, CharSequence password) {
                    Log.d("asdf", "valid: " + emailIsValid + ", password: " + password);
                    return (emailIsValid && password.length() > 0);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(RxView.enabled(loginButton));
```

And here's the log:

`emailIsValid call: 
emailIsValid call: 
valid: false, password: 
// I type 'j'
emailIsValid call: j
emailIsValid call: j
valid: false, password: 
// I type 'a'
emailIsValid call: ja
emailIsValid call: ja
valid: false, password:`

As you can see, `emailIsValid` is called twice every time I type a character, which means it's doing a regex match twice, which is kind of wasteful.

I looked up how I could make `emailIsValid` only call once per change, no matter how many subscribers it has, and I found the `share()` method. Here's what happens when I add `.share()` to the end of `emailIsValid`'s declaration:

`emailIsValid call: 
// I type 'j'
emailIsValid call: j
valid: false, password: 
// I type 'a'
emailIsValid call: ja
valid: false, password:`

That solves the problem, but it causes another: There is no initial emit by `emailIsValid` to the `combineLatest` function at the end, so the Login button starts enabled, when it should be disabled (grayed out).

What's the cleanest way to solve this? I *think* I want it to behave like a `BehaviorSubject`, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `publish()` and `connect()`.

```
val email = RxTextView.textChanges(emailEditText)
val emailIsValid = email.map { charSequence ->
  Log.d("asdf", "emailIsValid call: " + charSequence)
  Pattern.matches(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.pattern(), charSequence)
}.publish()
RxView.focusChanges(emailEditText)
    .withLatestFrom(emailIsValid) { hasFocus, emailIsValid ->
      (!hasFocus && !emailIsValid)
    }
    .subscribe { showError ->
      if (showError) {
        Log.d("asdf", "error")
      }
    }
val password = RxTextView.textChanges(passwordEditText)
Observable.combineLatest(emailIsValid, password) { emailIsValid, password ->
  Log.d("asdf", "valid: $emailIsValid, password: $password")
  (emailIsValid && password.length > 0)
}.subscribe(RxView.enabled(button))
emailIsValid.connect()
```

Or just switch the order of your `subscribe` because it causes the issue.

```
val email = RxTextView.textChanges(emailEditText)
val emailIsValid = email.map { charSequence ->
  Log.d("asdf", "emailIsValid call: " + charSequence)
  Pattern.matches(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.pattern(), charSequence)
}.share()
val password = RxTextView.textChanges(passwordEditText)
Observable.combineLatest(emailIsValid, password) { emailIsValid, password ->
  Log.d("asdf", "valid: $emailIsValid, password: $password")
  (emailIsValid && password.length > 0)
}.subscribe(RxView.enabled(button))
RxView.focusChanges(emailEditText)
    .withLatestFrom(emailIsValid) { hasFocus, emailIsValid ->
      (!hasFocus && !emailIsValid)
    }
    .subscribe { showError ->
      if (showError) {
        Log.d("asdf", "error")
      }
    }
```

Note: code is in Kotlin and more info about publish/connect is at http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#PublishAndConnect

**Your problem is similar to what mention there in PublishAndConnect section.:**

> The second subscription subscribes late and misses the first publication. We could move the invocation of the Connect() method until after all subscriptions have been made. That way, even with the call to Thread.Sleep we will not really subscribe to the underlying until after both subscriptions are made.

Comment: Awesome, wasn't aware of connectable observables. Works well, thank you!

Comment: @D_Steve595 NP. Glad I can help!

Answer (score 2):

I *think* what is going on here is the following:

- The first `subscribe` - the one at the end of `RxView.focusChange()...` - causes a Subscription to `emailIsValid` (and therefore also to `email`).
- `email` will then immediately emit the current content of the `TextView` as its first item, which in turn goes through `emailIsValid` and `share` and on to the first `Subscriber` (i. e. the `withLatestFrom` operator).
- Some time later the `combineLatest` causes another Subscription to `emailIsValid`. Since `emailIsValid` is `share`d, this Subscription does not "go through" to `email` and therefore each item will still be emitted only once.
- The problem is now that `share` behaves like a `PublishSubject`: It just emits *any future* events to all Subscribers, but it does not replay any of the past ones.

**In sum this means:** When the second `Subscriber` (the `combineLatest`) arrives, the initial value is already past - it was emitted right after the first subscription. And the next value will only arrive when you *change* the content of the `TextView`.

**Solution:** Try `replay(1).refCount()` instead of `share()` at the end of `emailIsValid` - that should ensure that each new Subscriber also receives the last previous evaluation result, as well as all future ones.

I hope that solves the problem and that my explanation makes sense.